# Deploying flask site/application on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment, pythonanywhere

I have a working sample site with the file system as such (https://github.com/alvations/APE):

```
APE
    \app
        \templates
            base.html
            index.html
            instance.html
        __init__.py
        hamlet.py
    config.py
    run.py
```

I have created a flask project on https://www.pythonanywhere.com and the file system is as such:

```
/home/alvations/
    /Dropbox/
    /mysite/
        /templates
            base.html
            index.html
            instance.html
        flask_app.py
    /web2py/
```

[image]

Where do I place my `run.py` in my pythonanywhere project?

How do I use the same file structure as my the project in my Github on pythonanywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here -- you don't need a run.py on [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com).  The code that normally goes in there is to run a local Flask server that can serve your app -- that's all handled for you by our system.

Instead, you need to change the WSGI file (linked from the "Web" tab) to import the appropriate application module.  So, because the sample site you have on github does

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

...on PythonAnywhere in the WSGI file you'll need to do this:

```
from app import app as application
```

One thing to be aware of -- if I'm understanding your file listings above correctly, you don't have all of the github app installed -- only the templates.  You'll need `__init__.py`, `hamlet.py`, and `config.py`, and they'll need to be in the same directory structure as the original.

Comment: Thank you, changing the WSGI file and keeping the original directory structure worked!!! Kudos to `pythonanywhere`, it made web deployment much easier than it was !!!